# How can I create a realistic glass material?

Tags: glass

I have a serious problem. I am confused about making real glass material. If you are able to help me, then I will be very grateful. Thank you! ♥

Material that I want to make:

[image: https://ibb.co/N2Smbcw]

My Shader Editor:

[image: https://ibb.co/Kzh7V2W]

Rendered image:

[image: https://ibb.co/TwYhQ1S]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please edit your question and upload your images to imgur by clicking on the image icon. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Use the Principled BSDF shader.**

1) Use only Principled BSDF node.
2) Set *Transmission* to 1 (to get physically accurate glass), *but don't touch anything else*.
3) Set *Roughness* as desired
4) Boom. You're done.

*Physically accurate glass using only Principled BSDF.*
[image]

Comment: ... or you could use the *Glass BSDF*.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :). I always thought *Glass BSDF* is the older, less accurate way to do it, however I may be mistaken. What are some situations where *Glass BSDF* is more appropriate?

Comment: For instance when you don't need any of the other parameters because you only need a simple glass shader without any blending with a diffuse or metallic material. The *Glass BSDF* only allows to control the *IOR*, *Roughness* and *Normal*.

Comment: I see. As I understand it *Principled BSDF* also takes care of a correct *Fresnel* value, and adds a *Transmission rougness* value, which together results in a more physically accurate material. But in some cases *Glass BSDF* is probably enough :).

Comment: I would have to look up how the *Glass BSDF* is implemented, but *Transmission roughness* from the *Principled BSDF* should be similar (if not equal) to the effect of the *Roughness* parameter. *Fresnel* is simply the effect of the reflection being stronger than refraction at grazing angles. The *Glass BSDF* has the Fresnel effect as well (otherwise it would not look like glass at all).

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my solution playing with the Glass and Glossy shader.

[image]